# Unable to copy Excel Map Chart using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm attempting to automate production of a PowerPoint presentation in MS Excel 2016 using VBA. I want to copy a Map Chart based on a PivotTable, and am getting "Run-time error '445': Object doesn't support this action".

I am using Excel 2016. I am trying to copy a Map Chart that is based on a pivot table, and cannot get the chart to 'copy'. I've tried recording a macro, but when I run the recorded code it produces the same error. I've included a simplified version of the code below, which is still producing the error for me. When I apply this code to other graphs (bar or line) in the same worksheet there are no errors.

```
Sub X()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsa As Worksheet
    Dim ch As ChartObject
     
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsa = Sheets("World Map")
    
    For Each ch In wsa.ChartObjects
        myleft = ch.Left
        myright = ch.Top
        ch.Copy
    Next ch
End Sub
```

`ch.Copy` produces an error. I expected to be able to successfully copy this, and add code to paste it into PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using "ch.CopyPicture" instead of "ch.Copy"?  It worked for me.

```
Sub X()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsa As Worksheet
Dim ch As ChartObject

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsa = Sheets("World Map")

For Each ch In wsa.ChartObjects
    myleft = ch.Left
    myright = ch.Top
    ch.CopyPicture
Next ch
```

End Sub